# Android/Java: How to ask location in background service when the app is not in foreground? onLocationResult is not fired in the FusedLocationClient

Tags: java, android, android-fusedlocation, android-thread

I try to ask the location with fusedLocationClient, the thread is well launching, I can see the Log.d("TAG", "Foreground Service is running"); but the problem is that onLocationResult is not fired...

```
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        shouldContinueLocationUpdates = true;
        if (thread == null) {

            thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    while (shouldContinueLocationUpdates) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "Foreground Service is running");
                        
                        
                        fusedLocationClient3 = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getApplicationContext());
                        locationCallback3 = new LocationCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                                if (locationResult == null) {
                                    return;
                                }
                                Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                                if (location != null) {
                                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                    longitude = location.getLongitude();

                                    // Utilisez la latitude et la longitude ici
                                    sendLocationUpdateBroadcast(latitude, longitude);
                                }
                            }
                        };



                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();
        }
        final String CHANNEL_ID = "Foreground Service";
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_ID, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        getSystemService(NotificationManager.class).createNotificationChannel(channel);
        Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentText("Foreground Service Running")
                .setContentTitle("This is Title");
        startForeground(1001, notification.build());

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    }
```

How to get the onLocationResult fired?